# MVC3 IPagedList in ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pagedlist

I want to have a page that has a form on the top of the page to enter movies in a system, and on the bottom of the page I want to have a table to display all of the movies in inventory.  I am getting an error saying: Value cannot be less than 1.  Parameter name: Page Size.

I have a viewmodel that currently looks like this:

```
public class InventoryViewModel
{
    public Inventory Inventory { get; set; }
    public IPagedList<Inventory> InventoryList { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller I have:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.MoviesList = new SelectList(inventoryRepository.Movies, "MovieId", "Title");

        InventoryViewModel vm = new InventoryViewModel
        {
            Inventory = new Inventory(),
            InventoryList = inventoryRepository.GetInventory.ToPagedList(page.HasValue ? page.Value - 1 : 0, defaultPageSize)
        };
        return View(vm);
    }
```

In my view I have:

```
<div class="well">
<h4>Enter Movie in System:</h4>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Movie was not entered in system. Please correct the errors and try again.")
    <div>
        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-film"></i></span>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Inventory.MoviesId, (SelectList)ViewBag.MoviesList)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Inventory)
        </div>      


        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBox("Quantity")
        </div>
        <p><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button></p>
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
    </div>
}
</div>

<div>
    <h3>Current Inventory:</h3>
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 15%;">Checkout Number</th>
            <th style="width: 15%;">Title</th>
            <th style="width: 23%;">Availability</th>
            <th style="width: 17%;"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var vm in Model.InventoryList.OrderBy(m => m.CheckoutNum))
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@vm.CheckoutNum</td>
                <td>@vm.Movies.Title</td>
                <td>@vm.isAvail</td>
                <td>

                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
       <tr>
          <td colspan="4">
                @Html.Pager(Model.InventoryList.PageSize, Model.InventoryList.PageNumber, Model.InventoryList.TotalItemCount).Options(o => o
                    .DisplayTemplate("BootstrapPagination").RouteValues(new { q = ViewBag.Query, area = "" } )
                    .AlwaysAddFirstPageNumber().MaxNrOfPages(5))
          </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: did you check to make sure you got data to InventoryList?

Comment: There isn't data, but it should load an empty table.  I realized that the defaultPageSize is never being set in the constructor.  That line should get the defaultPageSize from the web.config file.

Comment: `page.HasValue ? page.Value - 1 : 0` returns `0` when page has no value... what if you changes that to a value of `1`?

Comment: Same error, the first parameter of ToPagedList is pageIndex so that shouldn't matter if it's 0.  The second index is pageSize, and because the defaultPageSize isn't being set from the web config file, the pageSize is 0.

Comment: Ok, if I understand you, `defaultPageSize` is the problem and thats an appsetting

Comment: I'm stupid, since I was passing in an inventoryRepository I needed to add the line this.defaultPageSize... to the second constructor.

Comment: I appreciate the help again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  I was setting the defaultPageSize in the wrong constructor, so the variable was never getting set, causing the page size to be 0.

```
    int defaultPageSize;
    private IInventoryRepository inventoryRepository;

    public InventoryController()
    {
        this.inventoryRepository = new InventoryRepository(new MovieContext());
        this.defaultPageSize = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["defaultPageSize"]);
    }

    public InventoryController(IInventoryRepository inventoryRepository)
    {
        this.inventoryRepository = inventoryRepository;
        this.defaultPageSize = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["defaultPageSize"]);
    }
```